# In UIView drawRect, different translation (or meaning of self.bounds) if subviews are present?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, drawrect, bounds

I wrote a small sample program to better understand the meaning of `UIView`s property `bounds`. The program has one `UIViewController`.  I put a custom view inside it's root view, and override `drawRect:` on that custom view. And I add a button to "Change Bounds". Here's the screenshot.

[image]

Here's `drawRect:`. It draws a green dot at (x=50,y=60), and a gray rectangle over `self.bounds`.

```
CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSetRGBFillColor(c, 0, 1, 0, 0.5);   // green
CGContextFillRect(c, CGRectMake(50, 60, 10, 10));

CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(c, 0, 0, 0, 0.5);  // gray
CGContextSetLineWidth(c, 10.0);
CGContextStrokeRect(c, self.bounds);
```

Now I click the button which adds (20,40) to the `bounds.origin` of the custom view, like this:

```
CGRect bs = _testView1.bounds;
bs.origin.x += 20.0;
bs.origin.y += 40.0;    
_testView1.bounds = bs;
[_testView1 setNeedsDisplay];
```

Now, here's what the screen looks like:

[image]

You see the view itself has not moved on screen, but the green dot has moved. I think to myself: I get it, the `bounds` changes the portion of the view`s world that is mapped to it's area of the screen.

Next expermient: I'll add a subview. In `awakeFromNib` I add a label, as a child of the custom view, like so:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 50, 100, 100)];
label.text = @"Test";
[self addSubview:label];
```

At first, the screen is as expected:

[image]

But when I change the bounds, as before, things move differently.

[image]

It does not translate the view's coordinate system, like before. Why is that? Does adding to `self.subviews` change the meaning of `self.bounds`? If so, where is that documented?

Comment: I see different behavior when I make this test project. In the first case, tapping the button does not change anything, which to me makes sense because drawRect: will not be run again unless you say [_testView1 setNeedsDisplay]. But maybe I have not followed your steps properly.

Comment: Yes, I call setNeedsDisplay. I'll add that to my example code in the question.

Comment: Do you have Auto Layout on? The only way I could reproduce what you describe is with Auto Layout on (in which case it doesn't seem like one should be adjusting a view's bounds by hand anyway). But it's true that the behavior with AL on seems a bit unexpected.

Comment: Yes. It was on by default when I created this project, and I did not change it. I got into this rabbit hole because I was having a real problem with UIScrollView and autolayout, and the docs explained that UIScrollView works by changing it's bounds. So I wrote this to play with bounds and better understand the property.